# Comparing two lists inside two separate objects

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers, comparison

Okay so I've been tearing my hair out over this problem after several different attempts at it. To give some background and hopefully get an appropriate insight into this problem I'll explain how my code is set out.

- I have a list of pointers to players_, which contains two HumanPlayer class objects.
- Each HumanPlayer contains a Snake_List list attribute, and the pieces of these lists contain x and y data. I want to check the front of the first HumanPlayer's Snake_List's x and y co-ordinates against every piece of the second HumanPlayer's Snake_List's x and y co-ordinates.

My current code looks a little like this in the function that should do this:

```
    for(Entity* player : entityList)
{
    Player* p = dynamic_cast<Player*>(player);
    Player* p2 = dynamic_cast<Player*>(player++);
    if(p)
    {
        i=p->Snake_List.begin();
        for(m=p2->Snake_List.begin(); m != p2->Snake_List.end(); m++)
        {
            if (i!=m)
            {
                if ((i->x == m->x) && i->y == m->y)
                {
                    p->respawn();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this compiles and runs fine but the collisions don't give me the desired effect. Nothing actually happens. I really don't think I'm referencing the second HumanPlayer's list properly, but if someone could help shine some light it would be hugely appreciated :)

Comment: You realize that `p` and `p2` have the same value? Why are you trying to trick yourself by using obscure increment operators for no reason?

Comment: You do know `p` and `p2` both start out pointing to the same player?

Comment: @KerrekSB That's my issue, I have no idea how to point to the second player in the list

Comment: @JonathanPotter That is the issue I'm having, I don't actually know for to point to the next player in the list. The list line where it's declared (it's in another linked file) looks like this

       std::list<Entity*>     players_ { new HumanPlayer( "Solid Snake"), new HumanPlayer ( "Liquid Ocelot")};

I've been having problems with this for a while, thanks for replying though since I wasn;t sure if it was point to the same thing, although I have my doubts

Comment: Don't use a range-based `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are (and only ever will be) only two `Player` objects in the list, then you can get the two players like this:

```
auto itPlayer = entityList.begin();
Player* p1 = *(itPlayer++);
Player* p2 = *itPlayer;
```

This doesn't do any error checking so if there are less than two players in the list, it will crash. if you can ever have more than two players in the list, you would need to use a nested loop to compare each player against every other player.

The reason your original version wasn't working (apart from the post-increment in the wrong place) was that the *range-based-for* `(for x : y)` returns the actual objects in the list, not their iterators. You need the iterators to allow you to increment to move from one item in the list to the next, as the pointers themselves could be anywhere in memory.

Comment: Oh wow yeah, using the auto makes sense actually since as you said, there's only ever going to be two players. I think I was having some polymorphism problems too, as I had to change those last two lines to dynamically cast my Entity*'s as Player*'s, but this has worked. Thank you so much, you've swiftly helped me dodge another migraine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want '++player' instead?

Sorry, I should have been more verbose.  I believe the problem is you're indexing player *after* you use it in

> Player* p2 = dynamic_cast(player++);

when what you really want something like '++player'.
So something like

```
Player* p2 = dynamic_cast<Player*>(player) + 1;
```

So you cast to Player first then index to the next player.

Comment: I just tried that, but instead of running the program actually crashes when I do it that way

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is at the very top of your code snippet:

```
for(Entity* player : entityList)
{
    Player* p = dynamic_cast<Player*>(player);
    Player* p2 = dynamic_cast<Player*>(player++);
```

You iterate `entryList` and then check whether the head of `p` ran into any of the snake pieces of `p2`. However, you have to play some unusual tricks with the post-increment operator here.

I think what you *actually* want to do is to check whether the head of the snake of some given player ran into the snake of *any other* player. Writing the code with that idea in mind will probably avoid the post-increment operator usage, and it will scale nicely to more players.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative design approach. I think now that I've got the basic function working I'm going to try rewriting it like this to make the code more efficient.